# C# Linq DataContext Table: A polymorph cast

Tags: c#, linq, generics, polymorphism

I am trying to write a method:

```
public Table<ParentType> GetTableFromContext()    {
   //return a table of type Table<ChildType> 
}
```

Yes, I could solve this using Generics:

```
public Table<T> GetTableFromContext<T>() where T : ParentType   {
   //return a table of type Table<T> 
}
```

But I'd prefer not to. (I'd have to use generics in all base classes then)
Is there a solution to refer to a table with a less specific type?

Comment: Yes, you can return a `Table<ChildType>` from the first method, but how would you decide which subtype is to be returned?

Comment: @GertArnold Always the same subtype. I've declared a partial class, based on the dbml classes and set a shared base class on all of them. Now I want to get the table with that base class regardless the parent type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with the help of **covariation**, but at this case you should use interface `ITable` instead of class `Table` as return type of your method:

```
public interface ITable<out T>
{}

public class Table<T> : ITable<T>
{}    

public ITable<ParentType> GetTableFromContext() {
    return new Table<ChildType>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, your problem is "I want to return one of a few types, but I don't want a complicated inheritance". If this is so, your solution is a marker interface

```
public interface ITable {}
```

Which can be implemented (with no interface members it's very simple) by your return types

```
public class ChildType1 : ITable
```

Additionally, the interface can serve to enforce a common structure on your entities, if they have any (the most common example is probably an Id property)